# Multiple condition for single column not working Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table in mysql "razorpayfailpayments" and i want to count different "method"(payment failure source) in mysql

```
id              method              date                        hour                bank    
1               upi                 2021-07-07                  16                  1   
2               upi                 2021-07-07                  16                  1
3               wallet              2021-07-07                  16                  1
4               card                2021-07-07                  16                  1
5               netBanking          2021-07-07                  16                  1
```

I tried with following code

```
select COUNT(rf.id) as total,COUNT(case when method = 'upi' then 1 else 0 end) as upicount
from razorpayfailpayments rf 
where rf.date= '2021-07-07' AND rf.hour= '16' AND rf.bank= '1'
```

But showing me upi="3" values,I want result as upi=2 and wallet=1 , card=1,netBanking=1 as answer

Comment: You need to `group` your results, something like `select rf.method, COUNT(rf.id) as total,
from razorpayfailpayments rf 
where rf.date= '2021-07-07' AND rf.hour= '16' AND rf.bank= '1'
Group by method`

Comment: @AndreaOlivato:how can i count different methods ?

upi  card wallet netbanking
2  1  1  1

Comment: `COUNT(case when method = 'upi' then 1 else 0 end)` is equal to `COUNT(*)`. Use `SUM(case when method = 'upi' then 1 else 0 end)` or `COUNT(case when method = 'upi' then 1 end)` instead.

Comment: *But showing me upi="3"* ?? must show 5 on shown data.

Comment: This is either a pivot question (with series of conditional counts as shown by Akina) or it is  a group by with counts where the counts are shown in the rows as opposed to the columns. For both type of summarisation there are multiple answers already here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace latter `COUNT` with `SUM`, something like:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(tbl.id) AS total,
    SUM(
        CASE `method`
            WHEN 'upi' THEN 1
        END
    ) AS upicount
FROM
    razorpayfailpayments tbl 
WHERE
    tbl.date= '2021-07-07'
    AND tbl.hour= '16'
    AND tbl.bank= '1'
```